# Grails Scheduled Quartz Job never runs

Tags: grails, quartz-scheduler

Here is the Code:

```
class FollowUpJobOne {

        FollowUpMailService followUpMailService;
        static triggers = {
            cron name: 'jobOneForFollowUp', cronExpression: "00 00 6 ? * *" //6 AM everyday as per server time

        }
        def execute() {
            log.debug("control in Follow up job");
            followUpMailService.sendFollowUpMails();
            followUpMailService.sendFollowUpMailsForDandO();
        }
    }
```

*This Above Job never runs at 6 a.m. 
I am unable to find the issue.
Please Help

Comment: schedules end with `Job` as per answer below. Calling a controller `SomeNameControllerOne` will also not work it needs to follow the pattern

Answer (score 2):

Your class should ends with **Job**.
Just rename **FollowUpJobOne** to **FollowUpOneJob**

Answer (score 0):

1. use `grails create-job` to create a job class which should be end with `Job`
2. cronExpression use `0 0 6 * * ?`.  Not sure whether quartz can parse `00`.
3. confirm `autoStartup = true`

Comment: Think it's create-job http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-quartz/ref/Command%20Line/create-job.html